# dynamic branch with logic in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to set Jenkins job with parameters, that one of the parameters will decide the branch.
for example, if one of the Jenkins parameter is "A",
I would like to add this logic:

```
if A == "1"
  branch_name = master
if A == "2"
   branch_name = stable
```

I know i can add the branch_name as Jenkins parameter, but this is not what i want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive your goal by option `Prepare an environment for the run` with following job configuration:

1) Add a job parameter: A

2) check `Prepare an environment for the run` and `Keep Jenkins Build Variables` in job configuration

[image]

3) Fill following groovy script in  `Groovy Script` text box, and check `Use Groovy Sandbox`

```
if (binding.variables.get('A') == '1') {
    return [ "branch": "master" ]
}
else {
    return [ "branch": "stable" ]
}
```

[image]

4) specify branch name `*/${branch}`

[image]